# Detect systemwide mousedown-events in powershell

Tags: powershell, winapi, events

How to detect systemwide mousedown-events in powershell? The script should run 24/7

So far, I got this:

```
$key  = 0x01
$Signature = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)] 
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode); 
'@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name Keyboard -Namespace PsOneApi
$f=0
do
{   If( [bool]([PsOneApi.Keyboard]::GetAsyncKeyState($key) -eq -32767))
        { 
            $f++
            #Write-Host $f -ForegroundColor Green 
        }
    
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10

} while($true)
```

But don't know if this is the best approach, since working with an endless loop is maybe not the most efficient way to manage system-resources. Is there a solution with mouse-event-hooks and is this is favorable than endless polling for the right key-input?

Comment: Look at [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) with `WH_MOUSE/_LL` hooks. But I don't know if you can use that in PowerShell.

Comment: Since you asked, a script generally is not the best approach for something that should run 24/7, that sounds more like a Windows Service.